# CSS <label> float in IE9

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer, css-float

I have the following structure:

```
<form>
<ul>
<li>
<label for="#id">Item</label>
<input type="text" id="#id"/>
</li>
<li>
<label for="#id">Item</label>
<input type="text" id="#id"/>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

With following css on the labels:

```
width: 250px;
float: left;
display: block;
```

In all browsers i have:

```
label input
label input
```

In IE9 i got something like:

```
label input
      label
input 
label input
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What css are you applying to `input` ?

Comment: Only a border: 1px solid black;

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the float for the li and your problem is solved

```
label {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

li {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks seems to work. But: I have on the left of the form a navigation. Now the form is pushed down because it clears the float of the navigation. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear when you are floating:

css clearfix:

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Changes to your html:

```
<form>
 <ul>
  <li class="clearfix">
   <label for="id">Item</label>
   <input type="text" id="id">
  </li>
 <li class="clearfix">
   <label for="id1">Item</label>
   <input type="text" id="id1">
  </li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

Some remarks, your ID's a wrong, they must start with a letter.

Comment: Same problem as mentioned above. The last li in this ul is pushed down to the end of the height from the navigation, which is on the left of it.

Comment: then please post all your code, we cant solve this issue if we don't see the rest that influence the unwanted behavior